# live screen capture with a Windows 8 App

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, video-capture, screen-capture

i want to show my own live screen capture in a Windows 8 App.
With other projects, i used to use screen capture software that emulates a video input card with your desktop screen on your own machine (to then record or share the screen with other software).

The software: http://www.splitmedialabs.com/media-toolkits/vh-video-sdk/vh-screen-capture

http://www.videohelp.com/tools/UScreenCapture

I´ve installed and tested that software with VLC in my Windows 8.1 OS, and they work well, but if i try to use it in my App, it just can´t find the input video source.

Visual Explanation:

After installing the Unreal Screen Capture, for example, if then i run VLC and select "Media->Open capture device", i can choose the Unreal capture driver.

[image]

And if i play it, it shows my desktop, so the driver is properly installed on my system.

BUT, when i search for video capture devices within my Windows 8 App, it just can´t find any. Here is my javascript/WinRT code:

```
var deviceInfo = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation;
    deviceInfo.findAllAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.videoCapture).then(function (devices) {

        // Add the devices to deviceList

        if (devices.length > 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
                deviceList.push(devices[i]);
            }
```

I set a debug checkpoint at the "if" line and there are 0 devices found. Do you know why? Is there another way of checking and using the video capture devices from WinRT?

Note: I tested my code with a real video capture card and it finds it and plays tjhe stream perfectly well, so the problem is just with those screen capture software.

Another solution could be to implement by myself a live-screen-capture code. So if you know somehow to capture my own screen from a WinRT app, it could help.

Thanks!!

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd bed it has to do with the drivers being used. If I were you I'd investigate what the limitations for the video capture drivers are. I ran into a similar issue with Usb Serial drivers. You couldn't use the standard usbser.sys, you had to use the newer WinUSB.sys. Also, make sure that you have video capabilities included in your app manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is that i´m not using a "real" device to capture de screen, i´m using a screen capture emulator driver, wich emulates a video capture input (with my screen as input source). So, it doesn´t use a USB-driver (or i think it doesn´t)... I don´t know the driver they use, i just know they are implemented in DirectShow. In fact, i can´t find the emulated devices at the Device Manager in Control Panel.